# MS Access Update Issue

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've learned from this site the proper way to update an MS Access Database using parameters but now I have another problem. It seems that using Access as Database is not as efficient or user friendly as compared to using SQL Server. This is my code:

```
Private Sub btnUpdatePass_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdatePass.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that " & txtEmpID.Text & " is the Employee ID you want to change password?", "ALERT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            ChangePassword(Me.txtEmpID.Text, txtChangePass.Text)
        End If
End Sub

Public Sub ChangePassword(empID As Object, password As Object)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        query = "UPDATE Users SET Password = @password WHERE ID = @empID"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully changed password.", "CHANGE PASSWORD", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        GetErrorMessage(ex)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Whenever I press the btnUpdate I get an error saying:
System.Data.OleDB.OleDBException: Syntax Error in Update Statement
I have a table with ID As Number, UserName As Text, Password As Text. I don't know where my error is. Could you show me the way again? Thanks.

Comment: Check for reserved words such as users and password.

Comment: "Password" is a reserved word in Access SQL.  Escape it with brackets: `"UPDATE Users SET [Password] = ...`   Also, passwords should be hashed, not saved as plaintext .  Why are the params to the Sub Object?  Turn on `Option Strict`

Comment: Again Plutonix. You are very prompt and very knowledgeable. You have helped me before and this time again. If I may get some more of your time again and help me how to do the hash thingy. Is that something I must do in MS Acccess or in the program? Can you give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to put double quotes around the parameters.

```
query = "UPDATE Users SET Password = """@password""" WHERE ID = """@empID""""
```

Comment: Double quotes, or triple quotes?

Comment: This is not correct.  Param placeholders do not need quotes of any kind.